# How to add a local framework to a Flutter plugin for iOS

Tags: ios, plugins, cocoapods, flutter

So, I've been struggling for some time with embedding a third party framework into a Flutter plugin I'm writing for iOS.

The plugin is fairly straightforward, mostly just forwarding calls and events to/from the third party framework.

The third party framework in questions is for controlling a Sphero robot ([RobotKit.framework](https://github.com/orbotix/Sphero-iOS-SDK)).
This particular framework is an umbrella framework, with several sub frameworks within.

To include this .framework in my plugin, I've tried a lot of combinations between

```
preserve_paths
vendored_frameworks
resource
xcconfig
```

in the .podspec file to link to the RobotKit.framework package (inspired by [blog](http://codereaper.com/blog/2014/creating-a-pod-with-crashreporter/)), but without luck.

I can use

> vendored_frameworks = 'Frameworks/RobotKit.framework'

to get Xcode to detect the package and import the headers, but when building I get an error linking to a header in one of the sub frameworks (RobotKitClassic is a sub framework):

```
fatal error: 'RobotKitClassic/RobotKitClassic.h' file not found #import <RobotKitClassic/RobotKitClassic.h>
```

Am i approaching this the wrong way, or is there a trick that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up working around this by implementing the plugin functionality directly in my main app project instead of in a separate Flutter plugin.

Doing this, i can add the RobotKit framework to the Runner project and it links, builds and runs just fine.

Answer (score 1):

IF your case is nested frameworks to use the result in app then nesting frameworks isn't allowed in IOS , here from apple forums , I faced error like can't load frameWork @rpath to do this all code in dynamic framework must be pure code not pods or plugins

[image]

Comment: To clarify a few things: I'm not building the .framework myself, only trying to use it in my Flutter plugin. Also when using the same third party (umbrella) framework in a regular iOS Xcode project (ObjC) it builds and runs without any issues.

Comment: using it or creating are same nested isn't allowed all must be pure code no sub-frameworks

Comment: umberalla works if content inside framework is pure Code , and to try it , try to create adynamic framework and use pods inside it and take the result framework in any sample app , the app won't see the pod frameworks